# Demora no carregamento de alguns registros

Tags: php, mysql, query, zend, zend-framework-2

Olá!
Trabalhamos com SugarCrm. Quem não conhece o Sugarcrm é um CRM feito em mysql e php que usa o framework Zend. Utilizamos a versão opensource e fizemos algumas customizações.

Estou com o problema onde alguns registros de clientes demoram muito para carregar.

**Gostaria de saber qual a melhor maneira para eu descobrir o motivo pela qual esses clientes não carregam.**

Porque não são todos, é um ou outro, se fosse geral tudo bem eu ate entenderia que poderia ser alguma query dentro do mysql que esta com problema, mas não é, trata-se somente de um ou outro registro que demora a carregar e não é todo dia. Tem dia que esses mesmos registro carregam rapidamente e tem dias que eles resolvem demorar para carregar.

Gostaria de entender o porque isso. Se por um caso existe alguma forma dentro do linux (o servidor onde o sistema esta hospedado é em linux Debian) que eu possa monitorar e descobrir o que acontece com esses registros.

Obrigada

Comment: Não seria instabilidades da conexão com a internet?

Comment: Então é tudo interno, o servidor é hospedado aqui na empresa mesmo, não dependemos da internet para acessar ele, só para envio de emails mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode monitorar os recursos do seu servidor com o htop.

Para instalar: `apt-get install htop`

Para utilizar: `htop`

Para encerrar: Pressione f10.

Answer (score 0):

Bem temos um problema um pouco difícil ser rastreado, pode ser diversos motivos, mas vamos começar pela infra.

Solicito que você baixe o [ZendServer](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend_server) que tem sua versão de 30 dias, para análise completa do seu sistema, infra e banco. E aconselho a partir de agora usá-lo é muito excelente e agiliza muito sua vida.

Essa vai ser uma investigação complicada de fazer sem essa ferramenta, o htop não ajuda muito viu, então desejo sucesso! Posta mais detalhes.

Se esse for um gargalo em seu sistema, trabalho como consultor PHP e atendo diversas empresas no Brasil. Quem sabe se você não conseguir posso checar para você, mas espero que resolva com o ZendServer, no mais só vendo mesmo.

Grato

Ríder Cantuária

47 9 9168-8318 [whatsapp]